# Delphi D2009 for Win32 and the CodeDom

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Does anyone know whether it is possible (theoretically or in reality) to use the CodeDom that seems to be provided in Delphi's .NET counterpart?

Comment: Maybe a little clarification needed, are you wanting to use the CodeDom to view code created using Delphi 2009 or from within Delphi 2009 to view .NET code?

Comment: I would what the CodeDom to create code inside Delphi 2009 (Win32).

Comment: Clarification - What I actually want to do is load in code from a project, press a button and add standard headers, etc to each until in the project. I can probably write this with OpenTools, but this looked like a cool way of doing this

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the .NET CodeDom is really only applicable to .NET code generation. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: No, the .NET CodeDom relies upon code being compiled into [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and .NET ByteCode and will not work for Win32 Compiled Delphi Programs.

Comment: I thought as much, oh well, back to rolling my own!